# Error migrating DocumentDB binding to Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I am trying to use the WebJobs SDK extensions (and the Azure Functions tools for VS) to migrate my Azure functions to pre-compiled binaries, but I'm having problems with the DocumentDB bindings.

I'm trying to create an input binding to an existing DocumentDB document that I can read from, then update the data. When I do this in a script-based Azure function, everything works the way I want. Here's the code I'm using:

```cs
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, JObject document, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(document.ToString());

    var active = document["active"] as JArray;
    foreach (var item in active)
    {
        log.Info($"Polling {item}...");
    }

    document["processed"] = DateTime.Now;
    log.Info(document.ToString());
}
```

The document in question looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "sites",
    "_rid": "(hash)",
    "_self": "(stuff)",
    "_etag": "\"(guid)\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "active": [
        "scifi"
    ],
    "_ts": 1497184149
}
```

If I try to move this exact code into a pre-compiled function, using WebJobs attributes:

```cs
    [FunctionName("TimerFeed")]
    public static void Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        [DocumentDB("FeedStateDatabase", "FeedItemsCollection", ConnectionStringSetting = "feed_DOCUMENTDB", Id = "sites")] JObject document,
        TraceWriter log)
```

then I get an error trying to run the function:

`2017-06-11T12:26:36.046 Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerFeed. Newtonsoft.Json: Cannot create and populate list type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path 'active', line 1, position 219.`

Note that the error is thrown *before* any of my function's code runs. It is thrown even if I remove all of the code and just do a simple diagnostic log. So, I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my binding. The `functions.json` file that is being generated looks off, specifically it's claiming that this is an output binding:

```
{
  "type": "documentDB",
  "databaseName": "FeedStateDatabase",
  "collectionName": "FeedItemsCollection",
  "createIfNotExists": false,
  "connection": "feed_DOCUMENTDB",
  "id": "sites",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "document"
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using JObject type as your document - I've only been using dynamic or a POCO that represents the document structure.  Any reason you couldn't use one of those options?
I logged that github issue referenced in the other answer, agree that it's unlikely to be your problem here.

Comment: I can try dynamic, I was just following the Web Jobs SDK example.

Comment: No worries. Might be worth logging this on the Azure Functions github if you don't get a definitive answer here, in my experience they have been really responsive to  queries on there, particularly since the VS tooling was released.

Comment: Switching to `dynamic` appears to solve the problem; it actually looks unrelated to the binding direction (at least, the "broken" binding works fine as a `dynamic`.

Comment: Sounds like what I found - the binding direction didn't seem to stop my function from running as expected either.

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I haven't really gotten my question answered: I still can't use `JObject` for my binding, and manually fixing the direction didn't help. Switching to `dynamic` types merely circumvented the problem but it has other different problems of its own.

Comment: I tested with JObject, it works correctly on side.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I tried JObject, I also get null. If I use dynamic it crashes VS. If I use object it works fine, sorta.

Comment: As I mentioned I also get null with JObject during debug in VS. But If I publish it to Azure then it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) with the [Azure Function Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewBHall-MSFT.AzureFunctionToolsforVisualStudio2017) installed. After publish to Azure function, 
the code you mentioned could work correctly after change **direction** from **out** to **in** and add new documentdb connection string. The following is my detail steps:

1.Install Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 Preview and Azure function tool extension

2.Create Azure Function project and add timetrigger function add reference 
[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/)

[image]

3.Add the storage connection string to AzureWebStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard in the local.setting.json file

4.From the Azure [WebJob Extension SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) we cloud know that documentdb default connection string name is **AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString**. Add the corresponding value for it.

[image]

5.Add the following code in the timetrigger function

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [DocumentDB("database name", "collection name", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString", Id = "document Id")] JObject document, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            log.Info($"My property: {documents["MyProperty"]}");
        }
```

My test document is:

```
{
    "MyProperty": "hello1",
    "id": "a3e6a493-7c2c-4a73-8715-e7efad107d96",
    "_rid": "IgcwAN0Etg8BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/IgcwAA==/colls/IgcwAN0Etg8=/docs/IgcwAN0Etg8BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0600e070-0000-0000-0000-590152cc0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1493258955
}
```

6.I debug it in the local, I find that **document** always get null. I assume it may be the SDK issue.

[image]

7.Skip the issue and publish the project to Azure and I also reproduce the issue that Naren mentioned .

> Visual Studio 2017 tooling always generates direction out for DocumentDb

8.Then I changed **"direction": "in"** in the function.json manually.

[image]

9.Save the change and switch to **integrate** tab and create corresponding 
documentdb connectionstring.

[image]

10.Run the function from the azure portal, it works correctly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known issue. Visual Studio 2017 tooling always generates direction out for DocumentDb. For storage bindings like blob. FileAccess is used to identify whether it is an input binding or output binding.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/41

Comment: According to that issue, though, the incorrect binding isn't causing my problem :(